# How to mitigate the request limit TweepError in python?

Tags: python, twitter

I am **scraping** data from twitter for covid. My code was initially giving me outputs but now whenever I run the code I get the error "TweepError: {'message': 'Request exceeds account’s current package request limits. Please upgrade your package and retry or contact Twitter about enterprise access."
even though I upgraded my account in to an academic researcher account. I have tried delaying the code with time.sleep() but still does not solve the problem. Can anyone help with this problem?

here is my code:

````
 import numpy as np
import time 
from datetime import datetimeimport os
import tweepy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tweepy
import csv
import re
from textblob import TextBlob
import string
import preprocessor as p
#import os
import time
import requests
import json

#authentication. You need to put your own keys here 
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret= ''
access_token= ''
access_token_secret= ''

bearer_token = os.environ.get('')

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True)

# Define the search term and the date_since date as variables
search_words = "place_country:za lang:en covid"
date_since = "2019-11-03"
numTweets = 3000
#numRuns = 1

#this is the full archival search
#environment name needs to match the one for the generated environment on the twitter account
tweets=tweepy.Cursor(api.search_full_archive,environment_name='production', query=search_words,fromDate=date_since,maxResults = 500).items(numTweets)

response = api.rate_limit_status()
print(response)
tweets_details = [[tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.user.location, tweet.user.friends_count,
                                        tweet.user.followers_count, tweet.user.statuses_count, tweet.created_at,
                                        tweet.retweet_count, tweet.entities['hashtags'], tweet.text] for tweet in tweets]
# Insert into df
tweet_df = pd.DataFrame(data=tweets_details,columns = ['username', 'location', 'following',
                                        'followers', 'totaltweets', 'tweetcreatedts',
                                        'retweetcount', 'text', 'hashtags']) ```
````

Comment: Tweepy does not support Twitter API v2 endpoints or the full archive search academic package at this time, so you’re probably still hitting a premium API sandbox limitation.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, any suggestions on how I can mitigate this?

Comment: Sure, use a library that is not Tweepy. Twitter has a search-tweets-Python package that supports academic full archive. You’ll need to read the documentation.